# Скрипт водного знака

Tags: php

Всем добрый день. Помогите доработать скрипт водного знака на изображении.

Сейчас скрипт работает и накладывает водный знак и все бы хорошо но возник вопрос как сделать что бы водный знак ложился по середине картинки и был на всю высоту. Например картинка размером 2400 пикселей на 1800 для примера а водный знак идет 800 на 800 пикселей Как мне увеличить водный знак до размеров 1800 на 1800 и поставить его на центр изображения зарание благодарен. Вот скрипт:

```
<?php
header('content-type: image/jpeg'); 
// получаем имя изображения через GET
$image = $_GET['image'];

// создаём водяной знак
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');

// получаем значения высоты и ширины водяного знака
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);

// создаём jpg из оригинального изображения
$image_path = $image;
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);

//если что-то пойдёт не так
if ($image === false) {
    return false;
}
$size = getimagesize($image_path);
// помещаем водяной знак на изображение

$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 20;
$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 20;

imagealphablending($image, true);
imagealphablending($watermark, true);
// создаём новое изображение
imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagejpeg($image);

// освобождаем память
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);

?>
```

Comment: @alexsis20102, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению заданий. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.
alexsis20102, Пожалуйста, поправьте орфографию в вопросе, иначе он будет закрыт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
```

Очевидно, что размеры водяного знака задаются переменными `$watermark_width` и `$watermark_height`. А переменные `$dest_x` и `$dest_y` задают начало координат для вставляемого изображения.

Comment: если заменяем $watermark_width и $watermark_height на какое либо произвольное значение это не увеличивет изображение водного знака а просто создает область черного цвета. есть еще какие либо варианты ??

Comment: @alexsis20102 тогда нужно как-то растянуть ватермарк.

Comment: Вот об этом и есть мой вопрос как доработать скрипт так что бы водный знак растягивался и вставал ровно по середине.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `imagecopyresampled()` вместо `imagecopy()`.
Например,

```
imagecopyresampled($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width * 2, $watermark_height * 2, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
```